# Why this C programming can not run crrectly?

Tags: c

It's just a sample test that I want to unite the list Lb and La without repeat element. It didn't work, and returned -1073741510, I think maybe the array overflow, but I can't find where the problem is

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Union(char *La, char *Lb);
int ListLength(char *L);
void GetElem(char *L, int i, char *e);
int LocateElem(char *L, char *e, int (*comp)(char a, char b));
int compare(char a, char b);
void ListInsert(char *, int, char *);

int main(){
    char *La;
    char *Lb;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
        La[i] = i;
        Lb[i] = i + 5;
    }
    La[i] = '\0';
    Lb[i] = '\0';
    Union(La, Lb);
    for(i = 0; La[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        printf("%c\n", La[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

//unite La and Lb without repeat elements
void Union(char *La, char *Lb){
    int La_length = ListLength(La);
    int Lb_length = ListLength(Lb);
    int i = 0;
    char *e;
    for(i; i<= Lb_length; ++i){
        GetElem(Lb, i, e);
        if(!LocateElem(La, e, compare))
            ListInsert(La, ++La_length, e);
    }
}

//caculate the length of L
int ListLength(char *L){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; *(L + i) != '\0'; ++i);
    return i;
}

void GetElem(char *L, int i, char *e){
    *e = *(L + i);
}

//search the element e in L, if exist return the location, else return 0
int LocateElem(char *L, char *e, int (*comp)(char a, char b)){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; *(L + i) != '\0'; ++i){
        if(comp(*(L + i), *e)) return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//compare the element a and b
int compare(char a, char b){
    if(a == b) return 1;
    return 0;
}

//if e doesn't exit in L, insert the e in L
void ListInsert(char *L, int i, char *e){
    int j;
    for(j = ListLength(L) - 1; j >= i; --j){
        *(L + j + 1) = *(L + j);
    }
    L[ListLength(L)] = '\0';
    *(L + i - 2) = *e;
}
```

Comment: First problem is that you didn't allocate memory for La and Lb. Use malloc before your for loop in main() to allocate memory.

Comment: To make your code easier to understand: Use `L[j]` instead of `*(L+j)` and `e = L[i]` instead of `GetElem(L, i, &e)`.

Comment: Also, you can't just add data to a char array without reallocating (more) memory.

Comment: perhaps you could first write your question title correctly?

Comment: Actually, your real problem is your Coding Style, really. Also, you are reinventing the wheel, you don't need all these functions unless you're planning to handle another type of elements in the future, either way, this is not the way you should handle memory addresses in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this is wrong:

```
char *La;
char *Lb;
int i;
for(i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
    La[i] = i;
    Lb[i] = i + 5;
}
```

You need to reserve memory for `La` and `Lb`, for instance, by declaring them as:

```
char La[12];
char Lb[12];
```

An then this:

```
char *e;
for(i; i<= Lb_length; ++i){
    GetElem(Lb, i, e);
```

should read:

```
char e;
for(; i<= Lb_length; ++i){
    GetElem(Lb, i, &e); /* better yet: e=Lb[i] */
```

Finally, you're most likely looping one time too many by using `<=` instead of `<` as the `for` exit condition.

Comment: Looking at his original code, it should be at least La[12]/Lb[12], as he's also adding a NUL character at the end. Alas, +1 from me.

Comment: It would be `GetElem(Lb, i, &e)`.  He has declared `e` as a pointer, which he has also failed to initialize.

Comment: And don't forget his/her interesting way of adding new data to the char array... ;) Static arrays won't work for him/her, as he/she wants to append data.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, I finally find my mistakes(many ridiculous mistakes).And I think I should learn more about the storage in C, I declared a pointer but actually didn't allocate storage to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues. I think you need to read more about what are raw pointers, fixed length arrays, variable length arras and dynamic arrays. If you need your array to grow you can make it dynamic with malloc and realloc. Alternatively you can use a "big" array you know never will overflow.

```
int La[12]; //  0 to 10, plus '\0'
```

But this is fixed and cannt grow. You could use

```
int La[1000]; // if it solve yours problems
```

But in general you will need dynamic arrays.

Also, you need to deside if your array can hold `0` or it is used as terminator. `'\0'` and `0`, in the form you use it are equal. Many of your for cycle dont run because the first elemnt is 0.

Comment: Thank you very much, I always thought that '\0' is different from 0 before you told me, and I know where the problem is.I really think I should learn more.